# Cannot include client certificates on docker pull/push

Tags: docker, certificate, registry

I have set up a docker registry that is accessible only via localhost, and then a nginx proxy that would be accessible to the outside world, and would redirect the requests to the registry, if they are authorized.
I use client certificates for this purpose, following [this](https://fardog.io/blog/2017/12/30/client-side-certificate-authentication-with-nginx/) tutorial.

I finally got nginx running and authorizing correctly the requests coming from a browser (if I import the .pfx certificate into the browser server responds. If not, 403 is returned, which is the desired behavior).

I now try to communicate with my registry (through nginx) from a docker client, using login, pull and push:

```
docker login 10.11.2.7:5043
docker pull 10.11.2.7:5043/my-ubuntu
docker push 10.11.2.7:5043/my-ubuntu
```

The problem that I face is that, no matter what I have tried, I always get a 400 response with a small html saying:

```
No required SSL certificate was sent
```

Both the registry and the docker client that does the pull/push run under ubuntu.
The same problem happens when requesting the pull/push from both the same machine that the registry/ngnix run, and by requesting from an other docker client.

I tried

1. to follow [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/#understanding-the-configuration) tutorial without success.
2. to insert the certificated under /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/test and run

   sudo update-ca-certificates
3. to create the file /etc/docker/daemon.json and insert the following content:

   {
       "insecure-registries" : [ "10.11.2.7:5043" ]
   }
4. Restarted docker engine in all cases.

Still, the same error appears.

here is my /etc/docker/certs.d/ content:

```
10.11.2.7:5043/
  user.cert  
  user.key
```

Additional info: registry listens to port 5000. Nginx listens to 5043 (https). After every pull/push attempt, the following logs appear on nginx:

```
Aug 17 15:55:15 alkis-Latitude-E6530 dockerd[18438]: time="2018-08-17T15:55:15.323847790+02:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: error parsing HTTP 400 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: \"<html>\\r\\n<head><title>400 No required SSL certificate was sent</title></head>\\r\\n<body bgcolor=\\\"white\\\">\\r\\n<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\\r\\n<center>No required SSL certificate was sent</center>\\r\\n<hr><center>nginx/1.15.2</center>\\r\\n</body>\\r\\n</html>\\r\\n\""
Aug 17 15:55:15 alkis-Latitude-E6530 dockerd[18438]: time="2018-08-17T15:55:15.323944310+02:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.38/images/create returned error: error parsing HTTP 400 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: \"<html>\\r\\n<head><title>400 No required SSL certificate was sent</title></head>\\r\\n<body bgcolor=\\\"white\\\">\\r\\n<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\\r\\n<center>No required SSL certificate was sent</center>\\r\\n<hr><center>nginx/1.15.2</center>\\r\\n</body>\\r\\n</html>\\r\\n\""
```

My nginx.conf:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {


    map $upstream_http_docker_distribution_api_version $docker_distribution_api_version {
        '' 'registry/2.0';
    }

    upstream docker-registry {
        server registry:5000;
    }


    server {
        listen       443 ssl;  #ngnix is itself a docker container. The actual port for the outside world is 5043.
        server_name  my_registry.com;

        # SSL
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/domain_new.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/domain_new.key;
        #ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/conf.d/dhparam.pem;

        # client certificate
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/user.crt;
        # make verification optional, so we can display a 403 message to those
        # who fail authentication
        ssl_verify_client on;
        #ssl_crl /etc/nginx/conf.d/ca.crl;



        # Recommendations from https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;



        client_max_body_size 0; # 0 means no limit
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;


        location /v2/ {
            # Do not allow connections from docker 1.5 and earlier
            # docker pre-1.6.0 did not properly set the user agent on ping, catch "Go *" user agents
            if ($http_user_agent ~ "^(docker\/1\.(3|4|5(?!\.[0-9]-dev))|Go ).*$" ) {
                return 404;
            }

            if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
                return 403;
            }

            # To add basic authentication to v2 use auth_basic setting.

            add_header 'Docker-Distribution-Api-Version' $docker_distribution_api_version always;

            proxy_pass                          http://docker-registry;
            proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;   # required for docker client's sake
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr; # pass on real client's IP
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_read_timeout                  900;
        }




        #the following "location" section is only for testing purposes. It serves a couple of small html files.
        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }



        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `/etc/docker/cert/certs.d/` should be `/etc/docker/certs.d/`

Comment: You are right. It was a typo from my side on the posting of the issue.
It is indeed /etc/docker/certs.d/, but still does not work. I will update the description...

Comment: Is it the same error message with and without "insecure-registries"? In that tutorial you linked, ssl_client_certificate is set to ca.crt; what is user.crt in your case?